# Model pinball machine light

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

[image]

I like to model a pinball light as you can see in the picture.
Modeling it is not the problem but how can you get the inner pattern modeled. I don't know how you call that.

(Using Blender Cycles)

Comment: Can you show us what you got? It is probably easier to tell how to proceed from there

Comment: I'm not sure but for me you should create another question with the dome one light as answer will be different. Also revert original question here. Again I'm not sure, but this way looks right to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: Final]

I have slightly different method then @user3800527 it's quite similar but I've started making this answer before so I'll just post it.

**Before proceeding further enable F2 add-on in User Preferences.**

### Steps:

1. Create **Mesh** > **Circle** with 64 vertices (or as much as you want) and **Fill Type** > **Triangle fan**.
2. Select outer Edge of this Circle then **Select** > **Checker deselect**.
3. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> and Scale them a little.

[image: 1]

4. Most annoying step. Select each "inner" vertex, hover mouse to outer edge then press <kbd>F</kbd> to make new face.

[image: 2]

5. Select one of the outer vertices then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Select similar) > **Amount of adjacent faces**.

[image: 3]

6. Press <kbd>G</kbd>><kbd>Z</kbd> and move those vertices down a bit.
7. Select 3 vertices from outer edge again Select Similar then <kbd>E</kbd>><kbd>Z</kbd> and move them down.

[image: 4]

8. With still selected bottom edge press <kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>Z</kbd>><kbd>0</kbd> to make vertices even on Z axis.
9. Extrude them again and scale <kbd>E</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>><kbd>1</kbd> to make this edge a **Circle**.

[image: 5]

10. Before closing this shape, go back to the top of it, select one of the longest edge, again use **Select Similar**, but this time choose **Length** and move them down a little <kbd>G</kbd>><kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: 6]

11. Now we are ready to close this shape. Select bottom outer edge, extrude it up to cover our inner part, then extrude it again and close circle with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > **At center**.

[image: 7]

12. Now select top edge and **Bevel** it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, you can use mouse wheel to choose number of Edge Loops.

[image: 8]

13. It's almost the end. Select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to **Recalculate Normals**.
14. Select only outer faces, choose **Shading** > **Faces** > **Smooth** and turn on **Auto Smooth** in **Data tab**.

[image: 9]

### Edit:

**Lightning.**

For lightning I have used **HDRI** studio environment, as for example this one:

[HDRI studio](http://www.mrbluesummers.com/4701/downloads/free-hdri-map-photo-studio-with-umbrella) - this one is free to use. I've used one that I've created by myself.

**Material.**

For material I've used **Principled BSDF** from Blender 2.79 RC2 with this settings:

[image: nodes]

- **Roughness** for making it a little bit "milky". Play with this value to get desired result.
- **Clearcoat** to add extra shiny layer.
- **Transmission** to make it glass-like.

> Note that results may vary based on Camera angle, HDRI image and it's
>   strength, object thickness and such.

Comment: Hi, I finished the model. What lightning setup did you use and what material settings. In my model it doesn't look so realistic as your image

Comment: @vanlion I didn't save the file, give me a minute to recreate it and I'll make an edit to my answer. Lightning is for sure HDRI studio, and material is new Principled Shader from Blender 2.79 RC2, I'll upload exact settings in a while.

Comment: Nice for helping me and the quick response

Comment: @vanlion check my edit at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the top circle ?.

- Start mesh editing with a single circle plane object.
- Go to vertex edit mode.
- select all points.
- Select  >checkerbox deselect (in  menu select).
- with half of them selected now press g z and move your mouse up/down
- Select only 2 opposite vertexes and press F , that creates a line.
- from the tools menu on the left, do subdivide of that line
- from the centre create triangles to the border, this creates the shape.

When you got it you  might do..

- in mesh edit mode go to edge mode.
- select the outer edge of the circle (you might use edgeloop for that).
- Press E (for extrude) S for scale then Z and type 0  ==>  ESZ0 enter
- with still the current selection press GZ and move mouse up .
- thats a normal circle outer border.
- press E (extrude), S scale, move mouse to go for border width then enter
- press EGZ move mouse down..