# Pinball flasher dome

Tags: modeling

I had a topic/ question about a pinball flasher light with some great answers.

Can you do the same trick as in my other question to a dome flasher light you can see in the picture?

I tried it but couldn't figure out how tot make the dome
and the inside pattern.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: While I see you have got good answers to both of your pinball questions, it is generally better (and generally required) that before asking a question like this that you have at least *attempted* the problem, so we can help with a *specific* issue instead of doing the whole thing for you. This allows questions to be asked that will be useful to many people, as the question will focus on a single technique or method that may be applicable in many different projects, instead of a question that is only useful for your project.

Comment: Sure will do that the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note:
>
> This answer is connected to [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89845/model-pinball-machine-light) so I'll not go into details
>   as much.

### Final result:

[image: finsl]

### Steps:

1. Create **Sphere** and remove bottom half of it.
2. Add **Solidify Modifier** and set desired thickness. Apply this modifier.

[image: 1]

3. Select outer side of the object (you can select top vertex and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad+</kbd> couple of times), then hide it <kbd>H</kbd>.

[image: select]

4. From the inner part of the mesh select needed edges and scale them down.

[image: 3]

5. You can make bottom edge even by scaling it 0 on the Z axis.
6. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide outer part of the mesh.
7. Select all and **Recalculate Normals**.
8. In **Object Mode** choose **Smooth Shading** and **Auto Smooth** in **Data tab**.